# Probability question on an ant going across a vertex of a cube.

Tags: probability

An ant starts on a vertex of a cube. An ant-step consists of the ant choosing one of the vertices of the cube adjacent to its current vertex at random and moving there. (A vertex is adjacent to another vertex if there exists an edge between them.) After three ant-steps, what is the probability the ant ends up on the vertex opposite its starting position?

I am not sure what to do. I know the answer would be 1 over something and the denominator would a multiple of three but I can't figure out anything else.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Draw yourself a cube. Then count the number of paths of length three for the denominator and the number of those paths that end up at the other corner (for the numerator). You could warm up by solving the problem for paths of length two on a square.

Comment: The vertices divide into four classes:  the original vertex, the ones next to the original vertex, the ones next to the opposite vertex, and the opposite vertex.  You really only care which class you are in and the chance to go to each other class.  The symmetry makes counting much easier.  Make a cube and count.

Comment: It's easy to see that there are $6$ possible ways to get to the opposite vertex in $3$ steps. And there are $3^3$ possible three-step moves. So ...

Comment: Would it be 6/3^3 = 6/27